# Dialog not closing after printing with window.print

Tags: javascript, jquery, printing, dialog

Trying to print a div in a dialog. printing is working fine . but my problem is after print when the printing dialog closes after printing , my dialog does not what to close. 
Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on dialog prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'open'

```
  $.getById('DiaPrint').dialog({
        closeOnEscape: true,
        modal: true,
        width: 900,
        height: 650,
        autoOpen: false,
        draggable: true,
        resizable: false, 
        buttons: {
            'Print': function () {
                var restorepage = $('body').html();
                var printcontent = $.getById('DiaPrint').clone();
                $('body').empty().html(printcontent);
                window.print();
                $('body').html(restorepage);

                $.getById('DiaPrint').dialog('close');
            },
            'Cancel': function () {
                $.getById('DiaPrint').dialog('close');
            }
        }
      });
```

Need  my dialog to close after the print dialog

Comment: try $.getById('DiaPrint').dialog.close()

Comment: It's not working still getting the same error

Comment: Not sure why the message would say the attempted method call was _open_. But the problem likely results from emptying the body and trying to restore the contents afterwards with `$('body').html(restorepage)` - that will restore the HTML elements, but not any attached JS functionality.

Comment: You have set `autoOpen` to `false`.  Try adding `open` method. `$( "#DiaPrint" ).dialog( "open" );` - https://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/

Comment: Thank you for you contributions @random trying open is also not working

Comment: @Prince - It would be great if you can create a fiddle to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 0):

try this may be this helps-

```js
 setTimeout(function () { window.close(); }, 100);
```

Comment: thanks Ricky this didn't work also, still having the same error